# Android Sensor - MagnetSensor value always null

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get my head around the Android orientation sensors values for azimuth, pitch and roll.I'm using following coding

```
   mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
          mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);          
          magnetSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
       //  magnetSensor =mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED);
          mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
          mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetSensor , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {  
           case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                 gravity = event.values.clone();
               break;
             case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                 geomag = event.values.clone();
               break;
        }
    boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(inR, I,
                                                               gravity, geomag);
          if (success) {
                /* boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(inR, I,
                         gravity, geomag);*/
                 SensorManager.getOrientation(inR, orientVals);
                 azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[0]);
                 pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[1]);
                 roll = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[2]);
          }
```

i had tested Samsung Galaxy Core Prime (SM-G360H) mobile.. but the magnetSensor values always null and if condition also false. how to resolve this problem.thanks

Comment: You sure your device have MagnetSensor?.

Comment: GSM Arena's specs for that device doesn't list a compass http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_core_prime-6716.php

Answer (score 1):

```
private void getSensorList() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    StringBuilder strLog = new StringBuilder();
    int iIndex = 1;
    for (Sensor item : sensors) {
        strLog.append(iIndex + ".");
        strLog.append(" Sensor Type - " + item.getType() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Sensor Name - " + item.getName() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Sensor Version - " + item.getVersion() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Sensor Vendor - " + item.getVendor() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Maximum Range - " + item.getMaximumRange() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Minimum Delay - " + item.getMinDelay() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Power - " + item.getPower() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append(" Resolution - " + item.getResolution() + "\r\n");
        strLog.append("\r\n");
        iIndex++;
    }
    System.out.println(strLog.toString());
}
```

Use this method to check all your sensor.

Comment: The above code gives me a result like as   1. Sensor Type - 1
 Sensor Name - K2HH
 Sensor Version - 1
 Sensor Vendor - STMicroelectronics
 Maximum Range - 2.0

 2. Sensor Type - 8
  Sensor Name - GP2A Proximity Sensor
  Sensor Version - 1
  Sensor Vendor - SHARP Corp.
  Maximum Range - 1.0
 

3. Sensor Type - 65558
  Sensor Name - Screen Orientation Sensor
  Sensor Version - 1
  Sensor Vendor - Samsung Electronics Resolution - 0.0. i am not seeing any magnet sensor description in it. I want to clear one thing is this the reason for me to get magnet sensor value as null

Comment: It returns all your sensors in your device ,if you don't see magnet,it means your device do not has  magnetsenser.Not all devices got all sensors.If you don't have one, certainly you get null.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside your `onSensorChanged()`

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```